# Youtube wont fullscreen properly with Safari 9

Tags: macos, safari, fullscreen, youtube

After one of the latest Safari update (9.0.1 I believe) I can't use fullscreen option on Youtube properly. When I open youtube page and press F the player goes fullscreen, but the video area itself doesn't (and actually became smaller), so the rest of display is black and unused. If I press "space" (stop the video) or scroll using mouse the video area stretches to the full screen, but this is very inconvenient to press "space" twice each time I full screen.

I checked that the problem is still present when I sign out from my youtube account. But if I watch a youtube-video (embedded) on the other cites there is no problems with it. And there is no such a problem with Opera.

How to fix this problem? There are a lot of materials about it in the Internet, but most of it seems to be outdated. I tried to:
1. Press "Privacy/Remove All Website Data".
2. Uncheck "Security/Allow Plugins".
3. Disable extensions.
4. Press "Develop/Empty Caches".

This doesn't help.

Safari 9.0.2. OSX 10.10.5.

Comment: Just tested it out on my computer, same issue. I'll see if I can find anything. Update: I think it is probably an issue with Safari itself.

Comment: Yes, same issue here. It's very annoying bug. I have opened a Apple Bug Report. Please report this bug to apple. http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this answer just to "close" the question, since I don't have the problem anymore and can't test what is correct and what is wrong answer.

The problem somehow **disappeared after update 9.0.3**. I say "somehow", because right after I've performed the update the problem was still present, I noticed that it is not there anymore only several days after.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had that issue with YouTube, but similar things happen a lot with Facebook's videos and this helps.

1. Pinch with 2 fingers to zoom all the way out until you see this:[image: reference image]
2. Once you see this, click the YouTube tab again.
3. Hover over the URL Bar so you can see the refresh icon like this:[image]
4. Click on the refresh icon so that the page refreshes.

Comment: Sorry, but this is 1. unclear what to do. 2. doesn't it one time solution? then  "press space 2 times" is much faster and easier, but clearly not what I want, since I want to fix the problem, not to watch fullscreen.

Comment: I'm sorry for 1) being unclear, I have updated my post with more info, 2) not it one time solution, after you do this every YouTube tab you open should be fixed.  I understand that "'press space 2 times'" is not what you want, and that is why it is not in my answer.  This does not help with fullscreen, it help when closing out of fullscreen.

Comment: Ty, I understood now. It really does work, but only for the page I opened this way. So when I go to youtube in a normal way afterwards I see that the problem is still present.